# Ready made insite search for asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, e-commerce, search-engine

I have developed a business index which combines ecommerce websites.(in asp.net2.0+c#)

I'm looking for an in-site search engine that already handles issues like indexing, speed and quality.

Are there any famous solutions doing such?

I need the search results to be customized on my design, so google search engine isn't an option.

Thanks,
Eytan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself but I have read about [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) a port of [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at DTSearch?  It is relatively inexpensive and pretty full-featured.  Not great, but should be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

You need more details such as how you are searching. Searching against product descriptions in your database will be very different that searching against web pages that show those offerings.

Comment: Against product descriptions and specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft [full-text search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723263.aspx)